# Dynamically Generate Codes in C#

Tags: c#, enums, eval

I have a list of Enums like the following:

```
public enum Evaluation : int
{
    //Section 1

    S1_1_1 = 579,
    S1_1_2 = 584,
    S1_1_3 = 589,
    S1_1_4 = 594,
    S1_1_5 = 599,
    S1_1_6 = 604,

    //Section 2
    S1_2_1 = 610,
    S1_2_2 = 615,
    S1_2_3 = 620,
    S1_2_4 = 625,
    S1_2_5 = 630,
};
```

I want to iterate each section and use the values dynamically

```
int S1Count = 6;   

            for (int i = 1; i <= S1Count; i++)
            {
                VoteCount += string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.GetEvaluationValue(FormID, Evaluation.S1_1_ + i)) ? 0 : 1;
            }
```

How can I achieve that?  Thanks.

Sorry, my mistake.  I tried to get the value from the database by using enum values which are IDs and I have to calculate counts, average for each section.

Comment: Maybe by using reflection, but if they're really going to change often `enum` is not the best structure to keep them. Consider using a configuration file or even a database table.

Comment: It is fixed values and wont be changed often

Comment: Then why iterate like this? Just use a `switch` IMO...

Comment: Could you use multiple enums.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do with each enum value when you iterate them. @parapuras answer shows howto iterate an enum but not "each section" as you say in your question.

Comment: I think you could do with a slightly more complex object here. You seem to be trying to express a hierarchy in a flat structure. You want to be able to differentiate easily between the sections (as you have found) and the best way to do that is to have two different objects. Maybe you need a Section object that contains Item objects or something similar. Then you can easily pull out all the IDs in your section objet that represents section one and do whatever you want with them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) to do what you want I think though I don't reccomend it.

To use enum.Parse you'd just need to do something like:

```
Enum.Parse(typeof(Evaluation), String.Format("S1_1_{0}",i));
```

This does point at you using some dodgy methodology though. As I said in comments above you would be better off with a data structure allowing you to have sections and their contents easily differentiated. You can do this with either custom classes or maybe just a dictionary of Lists of ints...

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> SectionContents;
```

and use it like:

```
foreach(int id in SectionContents[sectionNumber])
{
    VoteCount += string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.GetEvaluationValue(FormID, id)) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

(I don't vouch for what's in the foreach, I'm just demonstrating how a dictionary of a list of ints could work).

Creating the Dictionary is easy enough and doesn't require enums. And if this is database stuff could easily be generated through a database query to get the IDs and what sections they are in and then create the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach (FieldInfo fInfo in typeof(Evaluation).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Evaluation." + fInfo.Name);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: The talk of different sections I assume refers to the different enum values in the same enum, differentiated only by comments at the top of each. I think this will mean having to do some parsing of the name inside the foreach...